# Issues passing arguments into script and between functions

Tags: bash

Afternoon all, bear with me please I am still learning bash.

I have a script that I want to pass two arguments to and call a function within that script to process the argument.

Script:

```
function checksum_download()
{
        # Check if the supplied hash is the same as the hash of the stored file
        if [ "$(md5sum < $1)" = "$2  -" ]
        then
                echo "Match"
        else
                echo "Fail"
        fi
        exit 0
}

./processing.sh checksum_download "/user/scripts/file.txt" d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

I know that I can call the function from within the script by adding `checksum_download $1 $2` however if I do this then it will be called each time the script is called and I have multiple functions within the script.

What is the easiest way to pass the function name and arguments to be processed?

Comment: Just put `"$@"` into your script.

Comment: Depending on the context, that could be a security issue though. If so, consider using a switch/case checking the first parameter to launch only recognized commands.

Comment: What does `processing.sh` do with the result of `checksum_download`? It might be simpler to run `processing.sh` from *inside* `checksum_download` if appropriate.

Comment: Unrelated, but it would be cleaner to write `if md5sum -c <(printf '%s  %s\n' "$2" "$1"); then`.

Comment: Also, it makes more sense for `checksum_download` to have just return the exit status of `md5sum` rather than outputting a string and unconditionally exiting with 0.

Comment: I.e., `checksum_download () { md5sum -c <(printf '%s  %s\n' "$2" "$1"); }`. (There should be two spaces between the `%s`s in the format string; comments make it hard to accurately reproduce code.)

Comment: Cheers guy, will have a look now.